# Funções Recursivas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções

Alguém poderia me tirar uma dúvida !

```
function recursiveFatorial(x){
if (x == 0)
    return 1;
else
    return x * recursiveFatorial(x-1);
}


console.log("Resultado da funcao recursiveFatorial: ",recursiveFatorial(10));

/*
Output
10! 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 =  3628800
*/
```

- Primeira vez que o codigo rodar, o valor de X = 10 e o resultado da expressão `return 10 * recursiveFatorial(10-1);` será igual a 3628800
- Segunda vez X = 9 return 9 *  recursiveFatorial(9-1); = 40320
- Terceira vez X = 8 return 8 *  recursiveFatorial(8-1); = 5040
- 4x,5x,6x... e assim por diante, minha dúvida é:

Quando terminar de rodar o código na 9x (ou quando o index X for = 1)
o resultado que a expressao -> [ return 1 * recursiveFatorial(1-1); ]
vai retornar tem o valor de 1, na proxima vez que o codigo rodar X 
vai ter o valor de 0 ! Então a condição (x == 0) vai ser true e retornar 1;
e não o resultado que está sendo printado no console de 3628800 !

Gostaria de saber aonde está sendo "armazenado" esse valor 3628800!

Não sei se consegui explicar direito!  De qualquer forma se alguém poder me ajudar entender como o console esta emitindo esse valor ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para facilitar a resposta, tomemos como exemplo o fatorial de 5.

```
var resultado = recursiveFatorial(5); // 120
```

A variável `resultado` será alocado na memória e seu valor será o retorno da função.

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Ao executar a função, o retorno será `5 * recursiveFatorial(4)`, então primeiramente o interpretador aloca na memória um espaço para calcular o retorno da função `recursiveFatorial(4)` antes de multiplicar por 5, como se fosse uma variável temporária:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Novamente, o retorno será `4 * recursiveFatorial(3)` e o interpretador precisará primeiro verificar o valor de `recursiveFatorial(3)`, alocando na memória um espaço para isso:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | recursiveFatorial(3) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

O mesmo acontece para 2:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | recursiveFatorial(3) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | recursiveFatorial(2) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

E o mesmo para 1:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | recursiveFatorial(3) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | recursiveFatorial(2) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | recursiveFatorial(1) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Finalmente, o valor de `recursiveFatorial(1)` será `1 * recursiveFatorial(0)`, então outro espaço na memória é necessário. Porém, desta vez, ao analisar seu valor, será 1, pois satisfaz a condição `x == 0`, retornando 1.

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | recursiveFatorial(3) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | recursiveFatorial(2) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | recursiveFatorial(1) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0006   |  temp_0     | 1                    |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Feito isso, o interpretador volta substituindo os retornos das funções pelo seus devidos valores:

Valor de `recursiveFatorial(1)`:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | recursiveFatorial(3) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | recursiveFatorial(2) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | 1 * temp_0 = 1       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0006   |  temp_0     | 1                    |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Valor de `recursiveFatorial(2)`:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | recursiveFatorial(3) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | 2 * temp_1 = 2       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | 1 * temp_0 = 1       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0006   |  temp_0     | 1                    |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Valor de `recursiveFatorial(3)`:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | recursiveFatorial(4) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | 3 * temp_2 = 6       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | 2 * temp_1 = 2       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | 1 * temp_0 = 1       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0006   |  temp_0     | 1                    |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Valor de `recursiveFatorial(4)`:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | recursiveFatorial(5) |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | 4 * temp_3 = 24      |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | 3 * temp_2 = 6       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | 2 * temp_1 = 2       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | 1 * temp_0 = 1       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0006   |  temp_0     | 1                    |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Finalmente, valor de `recursiveFatorial(5)`:

```
   Endereço     Variável            Valor
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0001   |  resultado  | 5 * temp_4 = 120     |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0002   |  temp_4     | 4 * temp_3 = 24      |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0003   |  temp_3     | 3 * temp_2 = 6       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0004   |  temp_2     | 2 * temp_1 = 2       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0005   |  temp_1     | 1 * temp_0 = 1       |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   0x0006   |  temp_0     | 1                    |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Portanto, o valor da variável será 120.

> Não foi objetivo da resposta descrever exatamente o funcionamento do interpretador do JavaScript, mas sim de descrever o funcionamento básico da recursividade, tendo em vista o contexto dado na pergunta, em que o autor deseja saber porque da variável não valer 1 se *aparentemente* este é o último retorno que ocorre no código.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do método recursiveFatorial ele chama o próprio método (recursividade )passando o valor de x - 1 , até o valor de x ser igual 0, sendo assim, como você passou o número 10, o console gerou 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1, se tivesse passado 20 seria:20 x 19 x 18 x 17...1