# Como se comporta essa função recursiva (função fatorial) em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Não entendo como o código se comporta após o mesmo sair da função recursiva na linha 7, `fat = n * fatorial(n-1)`, ou seja, como o código atribui o valor á variável `n` dessa linha e como é feito o calculo dessa linha onde o código atribui seu valor á variável `fat`?

Obs: sou autodidata.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def fatorial(n):                             #linha1
    print("Calculando o fatorial de %d" % n) #linha2
    if n==0 or n == 1:                       #linha3
        print("Fatorial de %d = 1" % n)      #linha4
        return 1                             #linha5
    else:                                    #linha6
        fat = n * fatorial(n-1)              #linha7
        print(" fatorial de %d = %d" % (n, fat) ) #linha8
    return fat                              #linha9

fatorial(4)
```

Comment: Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202519/5878) eu explico como é executado uma função recursiva para cálculo de fatorial em JavaScript. O lógica é exatamente a mesma e talvez seja útil para você.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Recursividade em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209187/recursividade-em-python)

Answer (score 1):

É um pouco complexo explicar isso mas vou tentar.

- A função fatorial(4) é chamada:
- A execução de fatorial(4) "trava" quando ela precisa calcular `fatorial(4-1)`;
- É feita uma nova chamada para a função `fatorial` em outro escopo com o valor de `n` sendo `3`. Essa nova chamada "trava" no mesmo lugar pois agora é necessário calcular o valor de `fatorial(2)`. Isso acontece até que o fluxo de execução chegue no ponto de calcular o `fatorial(1)`, o qual RETORNA o valor 1.
- Agora o FRAME da função `fatorial(2)` consegue o valor de retorno para substituir `fatorial(2-1)` e a execução continua.
- O print statement é executado e a variável retornada agora é o `fat` com o valor de `2`.
- Portando quando a função `fatorial(2)` foi executada, o valor retornado foi `2`.
- Esse valor será substituido no frame do `fatorial(3)` na linha 7, e assim sucessivamente.

Para entender como essa função funciona é necessário ter conhecimento sobre escopo de variáveis e frames de funções.

Tente acessar esse site aqui, ele vai te ajudar a entender: [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: até a parte que o código saí da função recursiva eu entendi, o que eu não entendi é como a variável "n" que fica entre o sinal de = e o sinal de * na #linha7 se comporta para atribuir o valor á variável fat, entendeu?, esse calculo que não estou conseguindo entender. OBS: já utilizo esse link para entender o comportamento dos códigos que estou estudando, mas valeu pelo aviso xD

Comment: Não entendi completamente o código, mas agradeço o empenho em tentar ajudar, valeu amigo! ;D

Comment: A variavel "n" tera um valor em cada frame. Primeiro tem valor 4 (quando chama-se fatorial(4)) depois eh chamado fatorial(3) e "n" entao passa a valer 3 e assim sucessivamente. Lembre-se que cada chamada de funcao uma nova instancia de "n" eh criada, ou seja, vc tem 4 instancias com valores diferentes de "n" criadas no seu programa.

Comment: acho que entendi, a cada chamada da função recursiva é como se a função principal tivesse varias funções dela própria aninhadas, né?, e a cada chamada dessas "funções aninhadas" fosse decrementado o valor de n-1 das funções recursivas, me corrija se eu estiver errado, acho que é isso!

Comment: se eu entendi o que vc quis dizer, é isso mesmo. Várias instâncias de "n" são criadas, uma cada escopo, uma para cada chamada da função fatorial(n). Cada 'n' independente do outro, com valor diferente e "vivo" somente durante a execução da chamada recursiva. Caso tenha resolvido a sua dúvida marca como "respondido" a minha pergunta pra dar aquela força