# Determinar o n-ésimo termo de Fibonacci com recursividade

Tags: python, funções, recursão

Não estou entendendo nada sobre funções recursivas, mesmo debugando, está muito confuso pra mim. Alguém consegue me explicar de uma forma fácil?

Tentei analisar o seguinte código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def fibonacci(n):                            #linha1
    if n<=1:                                 #linha2
        return n                             #linha3
    else:                                    #linha4
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2) #linha5    

fibonacci(5)                                 #linha6
```

Comment: A recursividade funciona da mesma forma, independente da situação. Você já abriu esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209043/5878) pedindo sobre como funciona a recursividade, então acho que será melhor você [edit] a pergunta e colocar EXATAMENTE qual é a sua dificuldade. O que você não está entendendo? A minha resposta em JavaScript não te ajudou em nada?

Comment: Você não entende recursividade ou fibonacci?

Comment: Sabe fazer teste de mesa?

Comment: então galera, o que eu não to entendendo é como os códigos trabalham na recursividade, o código em javascript não me ajudou 100%, clareou um pouco como a recursividade funciona, mas não sanou minhas duvidas.

Comment: @Eduardo se a resposta sanou sua dúvida, você pode aceitá-la pressionando o ícone **✓** no lado esquerdo da mesma.

Answer (score 23):

Vamos considerar o trecho de código que você colocou na pergunta, apenas atribuindo o retorno da chamada a uma variável, para simplificar a explicação:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

resultado = fibonacci(5)
```

A memória no computador possui um endereço e um valor. Para fins didáticos, vamos supor que esta memória seja sequencial, iniciando no endereço 0x01 e que possui uma etiqueta, referente ao nome da variável:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O programa irá executar a última linha do código, reservando um espaço na memória para a variável e definido o retorno da função como sendo seu valor:

```
resultado = fibonacci(5)
```

Na memória fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 1

Para saber qual valor de `fibonacci(5)`, a função `fibonacci` é executada:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 5`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)`;

Ou seja, o valor de `fibonacci(5)` será `fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)`. Então na memória, ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 2

Então, o programa irá tentar primeiro calcular o valor de `fibonacci(4)`, pois a expressão é analisada da esquerda para a direita:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 4`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)`;

Ou seja, o valor de `fibonacci(4)` será `fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)`. Então na memória, ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 3

Então, para saber o valor de `fibonacci(4)`, o programa precisa saber o valor de `fibonacci(3)` e `fibonacci(2)`. Analisando da esquerda para a direita, primeiro é calculado `fibonacci(3)`:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 3`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)`;

Ou seja, o valor de `fibonacci(3)` será `fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)`. Então na memória, ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 4

A mesma lógica: para saber o valor de `fibonacci(3)`, antes é necessário saber o valor de `fibonacci(2)` e `fibonacci(1)`. Da esquerda para a direita, calcula-se o valor de `fibonacci(2)`:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 2`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)`;

Ou seja, o valor de `fibonacci(2)` será `fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)`. Então na memória, ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 5

Para calcular o valor de `fibonacci(2)` então é preciso de `fibonacci(1)` e `fibonacci(0)`. Da esquerda para a direita, calcula-se primeiro `fibonacci(1)`:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 1`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Verdadeiro;
3. Retorne o valor de `n` (1);

Neste ponto, a recusividade é interrompida brevemente, pois o valor não depende mais de uma outra chamada da função. Assim, na memória fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 6

Assim, tendo o valor de `fibonacci(1)`, este é substituído em `fibonacci(2)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 7

Mas ainda é necessário calcular o valor de `fibonacci(0)`:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 0`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Verdadeiro;
3. Retorne o valor de `n` (0);

Então na memória fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 8

Este valor é prontamente substituído no valor de `fibonacci(2)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 9

O valor de `fibonacci(2)` é obtido somando 1+0 = 1 e é substituído em `fibonacci(3)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 10

Para calcular o valor final de `fibonacci(3)` é preciso o valor de `fibonacci(1)` novamente, então é feito novamente a chamada:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 1`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Verdadeiro;
3. Retorne o valor de `n` (1);

Ficando na memória:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 11

Este valor é prontamente substituído em `fibonacci(3)`, ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 12

O valor de `fibonacci(3)` então valerá 1+1 = 2, sendo substituído em `fibonacci(4)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 13

Mas novamente é preciso o valor de `fibonacci(2)`, então:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 2`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)`;

Ficando na memória:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 14

Já sabemos que `fibonacci(1)` retornará 1 e `fibonacci(0)` retornará 0, então para simplificar, colocarei direto seus valores em `fibonacci(2)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 15

Ficando o valor de `fibonacci(2)` igual a 1+0 = 1, sendo prontamente substituído em `fibonacci(4)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 16

Assim, o valor de `fibonacci(4)` ficará igual à 2+1 = 3, sendo prontamente substituído em `fibonacci(5)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 17

Para calcular ainda o valor final de `fibonacci(5)` é necessário o valor de `fibonacci(3)`:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 3`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)`;

Ou seja, o valor de `fibonacci(3)` será `fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 18

Analisando da esquerda para a direita, novamente calcula-se o valor de `fibonacci(2)`:

1. A função `fibonacci` é chamada com parâmetro `n = 2`;
2. Verifica-se se `n` é menor ou igual a 1. Falso, executa o `else`;
3. Retorne o valor de `fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)`;

Ficando na memória:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 19

Como já sabemos, `fibonacci(1)` vale 1 e `fibonacci(0)` vale 0, então substituindo os valores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 20

Resultando em `fibonacci(2)` igual a 1+0 = 1, sendo prontamente substituído em `fibonacci(3)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 21

Falta ainda calcular o valor de `fibonacci(1)`, que já sabemos que vale 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 22

Assim, o valor de `fibonacci(3)` será 1+1 = 2, sendo prontamente substituído em `fibonacci(5)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Passo 23

Finalmente, o valor de `fibonacci(5)` valerá 3+2 = 5, sendo substituído prontamente em `resultado`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, quando for executado:

```
resultado = fibonacci(5)
```

O valor de `resultado` será 5. Valor este que pode ser comprovado executando o código.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/5xQpJ3).

Comment: Se quiser tente simplificar as tabelas deixando menos largas e assim tirando muito espaço. Outra opção é colar imagens em vez de texto.

Answer (score 3):

Recursão é uma função que tem uma base definida, no caso do Fibonacci foi que `fib(1) = 1`, e `fib(0) = 0`, pois se `n <= 1` , return `n`. Caso o argumento passado para a função não seja igual a base ela chama a própria função com parâmetros modificados, como por exemplo `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`, ela faz esse processo ate que o valor dado como argumento seja igual a base. Quando enfim ela encontra os valores da base, ela começa a resolver rodas as função que foram chamadas.

Por exemplo, para resolver `fib(5)`:

- `fib(5)` chama `fib(4)` e `fib(3)`
- `fib(4)` chama `fib(3)` e `fib(2)`
- `fib(3)` chama `fib(2)` e `fib(1)`
- `fib(2)` chama `fib(1)` + `fib(0)`, então encontramos a base.

Substituindo

```
fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3) = 

( fib(3) + fib(2) ) + ( fib(2) + fib(1) ) =

( ( fib(2) + fib(1) ) + ( fib(1) + fib(0) ) ) + ( ( fib(1) + fib(0) ) + fib(1) )

( ( ( fib(1) + fib(0) ) + fib(1) ) + ( fib(1) + fib(0) ) ) + ( ( fib(1) + fib(0) ) + fib(1) )
```

Agora que é possível determinar todos os valores, substituímos por números:

```
( ( 1 + 0 ) + 1 ) + ( 1 + 0 ) ) + ( ( 1 + 0 ) + 1 )

( ( 1 + 1 ) + 1  ) + ( 1 + 1 )
( 2 + 1) + 2
3 + 2
5
```

Portanto, o `fib(5)` é 5

Answer (score 0):

Cara, já tive dificuldade em *fibonacci* também, é o seguinte, recomendo a criar duas variáveis, uma que recebe o valor atual e outra que recebe o valor anterior e tudo isso você coloca em uma estrutura de repetição, fiz com o `For`, segue abaixo um *fibonacci* que fiz usando o VISUALG em português.

```
insira o código aqui algoritmo "semnome"

var

c,fi, ant, at: inteiro

inicio

at <- 1

ant <- 0

para c <- 1 ate 15 faca

fi <- at + ant

ant <- at

at <- fi

escreva(fi)


fimpara


fimalgoritmo
```

se tiver alguma duvida, é só perguntar

Comment: então cara, como eu sou iniciante em programação e estou acompanhando os exercícios de um livro, eu teria que entender especificamente sobre como esse exercício se comporta, pra depois pegar referências de como fazer a mesma coisa só que de forma diferente, entendeu?, mas agradeço a tentativa !

Comment: Entendi cara, mas blz, continue estudando

Comment: @JoãoVictorCarvalho, tem como formatar melhor o pseudocódigo? Só por quatro espaços antes da linha de código, identando blocos internos (todos os comandos dentro do bloco `para-faça-fimpara` destacado mais para a direita que o código de fora)

Answer (score 0):

Um função recursiva é mais ou menos um função que chama outra só que no caso funciona assim:

Código de exemplo:

```
def fatorial (n):
    if n <= 0:
        return n
    else:
        return n*fatorial(n-1)
```

Explicação:
O que realmente está acontecendo é eu passo um valor para min mesmo e guardo ele e passo esse valor(-1) de novo e pego o antigo e multiplico com o novo até que eu não passo mais valor para min mesmo podendo passar outro valor para outra pessoa.