# Recursividade em PHP

Tags: php

Para onde vai o `return $num*fatorial($num-1);` ?

Coloquei um `echo` antes da condição e de forma decrescente exibe 5 4 ... 1, só não consigo entender para onde vai esse `return` e como `return $num` vai me retornar o fatorial se `$num` é igual(==) a 1, se alguém poder me esclarecer.

```
 function fatorial($num){
        echo $num; 
        if($num == 1){
            return $num;
        }
        return $num*fatorial($num-1);
    }
    echo fatorial(5);
```

Comment: Eu expliquei isso de maneira bem simples e visual [nesta pergunta sobre o cálculo de Fibonacci em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209220/5878). Não é PHP, nem fatorial, mas o processo é exatamente um mesmo. E é Python, então mesmo nunca utilizado a linguagem, você conseguirá entender o que o código faz (que é basicamente a mesma coisa que o seu em PHP faz).

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: [Imagem de Exemplo](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigos/img_artigos/Ricardo_Alves/Java_Recursividade/image001.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Quando o `fatorial` é chamado dentro do:

```
return $num*fatorial($num-1);
```

O `$num` é subtraído por `-` (em `fatorial($num-1)`), então o `$num` que começou com `5` na próxima chamada será `4`, quando chegar ao `fatorial($num-1);` novamente vai ser reduzido `-1` novamente.

Assim que `($num-1)` tiver **o valor** de `1` ao chamar o `fatorial()`, ele vai entrar na sua `if`, que é compara se `$num` é igual a `1`, então neste momento ocorrerá o `return` "prematuro" que vai terminar a função dentro da `if`, o que irá retornar o valor atual `return $num;` que no caso é `1` mesmo.

Então o processo ocorrerá assim:

- O input será `5`
- ignora o `if ($num == 1)`
- O retorno *"5 multiplica por `fatorial(5-1)`"*
- O input agora será `4` (antes de terminar a multiplicação)
- ignora o `if ($num == 1)`
- O retorno *"4 multiplica por `fatorial(4-1)`"*
- O input agora será `3` (antes de terminar a multiplicação)
- ignora o `if ($num == 1)`
- O retorno *"3 multiplica por `fatorial(3-1)`"*
- O input agora será `2` (antes de terminar a multiplicação)
- ignora o `if ($num == 1)`
- O retorno *"2 multiplica por `fatorial(2-1)`"*
- O input agora será `1` (antes de terminar a multiplicação)
- Entra no `if ($num == 1)`
- O retorno irá retornar o valor de `$num`, que conforme a `if` é esperado `1` (ocorrerá o `return` "prematuro" que citei)

Agora ocorre o resto do processo de volta (recursividade):

- Era esperado *"2 multiplica por `fatorial(2-1)`"*, o ultimo retorno foi `1`, então é `2*1=2` e envia para o retorno
- Era esperado *"3 multiplica por `fatorial(3-1)`"*, o ultimo retorno foi `2`, então é `3*2=6` e envia para o retorno
- Era esperado *"4 multiplica por `fatorial(4-1)`"*, o ultimo retorno foi `6`, então é `4*6=24` e envia para o retorno
- Era esperado *"5 multiplica por `fatorial(5-1)`"*, o ultimo retorno foi `24`, então é `5*24=120` e envia para o retorno