# Explicação do funcionamento de recursividade

Tags: c, lógica, recursão

Eu estou no inicio dos estudos de analise de sistema e estou aprendendo linguagem de programação. Nos estudos de linguagem C eu comecei a ver recursividade e alguns códigos que possuem a recursividade eu fico perdido e acabo não entendendo. Estou com dúvida nesse simples código:

```
int func(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return (1);
    } else {
        return (func(n-1)-n);
    }
}

int main(){
    int a,b;
    printf("Digite um valor inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    b=func(a);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Porque se eu digitar o inteiro 5, meu resultado será -14? Eu não estou entendendo o que o `return (func(n-1)-n)` faz.

Comment: Fiz uma resposta sobre recursividade em Python, [Determinar o n-ésimo termo de Fibonacci com recursividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209187/5878), veja se te ajuda em algo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pergunta principal seria "*o que sua função quer fazer?*". O que ela faz é decrementar o número digitado em um e subtraí-lo do resultado final, então:

- `func(5)` retorna o resultado de `func(4) - 5`
- `func(4)` retorna o resultado de `func(3) - 4`
- `func(3)` retorna o resultado de `func(2) - 3`
- `func(2)` retorna o resultado de `func(1) - 2`
- `func(1)` retorna o resultado de `func(0) - 1`
- `func(0)` retorna o resultado de `1`

Analisando isso, teríamos no final a operação `1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5`, que resulta em **-14**.

A forma mais fácil de entender é entender o que coloquei como *pergunta principal*; feito isso, você consegue formular uma lógica e treinar recursividade pra não se embananar..

---

Tratando mais especificamente sua pergunta, o trecho `return (func(n-1)-n)` retorna para a chamada; ele chama o método `func()` passando o valor de *n-1* subtraído do valor de *n*. 
Sendo `n` igual a *12*, `return (func(n-1)-n)` retorna o valor retornado pela chamada `func(11) - 12`.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, com a sua explicação eu entendi. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 6):

E iterativo você entende?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : func(n - 1) - n;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("Digite um valor inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", func(a));
    //agora iterativo
    int n = a;
    int temp = 1;
    while (1) {
        temp -= n; //faz a acumulação na mão
        n--; //faz o n - 1 guardando seu próprio estado
        if (n == 0) break; //condição de saída, poderia estar no próprio while com condição invertida
    }
    printf("%d\n", temp);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4LDMOB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hqyeknvm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/RecursiveExplain.c).

Eu escrevi o código iterativo de uma forma que não é o ideal só para visualizar mais fácil. E escrevi como se costuma escrever o código funcional, em apenas uma linha.

Os códigos estão fazendo a mesma coisa. Só que de forma invertida. Em estilo mais funcional, que é o recursivo você elimina uma variável porque o estado vai sendo passado em cada chamada da função. Na estilo mais imperativo você precisa da variável de controle do resultado.

O que está fazendo no seu código e chamar a mesma função uma vez atrás da outra passando o valor da variável sempre subtraindo 1, e considerando o resultado sempre subtraindo o valor do estado do momento, no caso representado por `n`. Em cada chama o `n` valerá um valor a menos  até chegar em 0, quando ele considera apenas ser 1, é a condição de saída.

Então chama assim:

`func(5)` chama `func(4) - 5` que chama `func(3) - 4` que chama `func(2) - 3` que chama `func(1) - 2` que chama `func(0) - 1` e aí como `func()` recebe 0 ele cai na outra condição e retorna 1 sem chamar mais nada. Note que ele vai formando uma pilha de chamadas da função (o termo usado oficialmente é este mesmo).

Aí no retorno da chamada de `func(1) - 2` é -1, já que `func(0)` sabemos que é 1. E o retorno desta é -2, e o retorno da seguinte é -3 , e depois retorna -4, e finalmente retorna -5. Se você acumular tudo isso terá -14.

Minha sugestão para entender melhor é ver executando, coloque esse código para executar em um IDE, ligue um *breakpoint*, mande parar na primeira linha e vá executando passo a passo, e veja como vai tudo sendo chamado, como os valores vão modificando. Não tem maneira melhor de entender o funcionamento do computador no algoritmo que está tentando identificar o que ele faz.

Comment: Eu também entendi o seu código, na minha cabeça eu não estava continuando a função até o seu ponto de parada que seria n==0. Eu preciso procurar alguns exercícios de recursividade para fixar mais o aprendizado e preciso aprender a fazer o teste de mesa.