# Torre de Hanoi - Como funciona essa solução recursiva?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Alguém poderia me explicar a lógica desta função recursiva? Não estou conseguindo entender do `if` para baixo. O código resolve o [problema da Torre de Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi):

```
def toweOFhanoi(disc,ori,dest,aux):
    if disc == 1:
        print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower{}'.format(disc,ori,dest))
        return

    toweOFhanoi(disc - 1,ori,aux,dest)
    print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower {}'.format(disc,ori,dest))
    toweOFhanoi(disc - 1,aux,ori,dest)
    print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower {}'.format(disc,ori,dest))
```

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/towers_of_hanoi.php

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer saber como funciona certo? Se sim a função em questão ela esta comparando a possibilidade de movimentação seja ela na torre ou para a torre.
Se não for isso por favor reformule a pergunta.

Comment: "Não estou conseguindo entender do `if` para baixo". Mais fácil você falar que não entendeu nada... hahaha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiro, a função está errada, tem um `print` a mais e a segunda chamada recursiva trocou a ordem das torres:

```
def hanoi(disc, ori, dest, aux):
    if disc == 1:
        print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower {}'.format(disc, ori, dest))
        return

    hanoi(disc - 1, ori, aux, dest)
    print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower {}'.format(disc, ori, dest))
    hanoi(disc - 1, aux, dest, ori)
```

---

Agora, ao problema. O [problema da Torre de Hanói](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) consiste em mover uma quantidade de discos de uma torre para outra (sendo que há uma terceira torre auxiliar). Os discos têm tamanhos diferentes, e um disco nunca pode ser colocado em cima de outro menor que ele. Além disso, só um disco pode ser movido por vez.

O `if` trata do caso mais básico: quando há apenas 1 disco. Nesse caso a solução é fácil: mova o disco da torre inicial para a final, ou seja, da origem (`ori`) para o destino (`dest`).

Mas e se tivermos mais de um disco? Nesse caso, supondo que as torres são A (origem), B (destino) e C (auxiliar), a ideia do algorimo é (para N discos):

1. resolva o problema para N - 1 discos, só que movendo de A para C (ou seja, usando C como destino e B como auxiliar)
2. mova 1 disco de A para B (da origem para o destino)
3. resolva o problema para N - 1 discos, só que movendo de C para B (ou seja, C é a origem, B é o destino e A é o auxiliar)

É isso que as chamadas recursivas estão fazendo. `hanoi(disc - 1, ori, aux, dest)` corresponde ao passo 1 acima. O `print` logo em seguida é o passo 2, e `hanoi(disc - 1, aux, dest, ori)` é o passo 3.

O grande truque é que cada uma dessas chamadas recursivas pode gerar outras chamadas recursivas, até chegarem no caso em que só tem um 1 disco, que é quando elas retornam e voltam imprimindo os respectivos passos.

Por exemplo, se eu tiver 5 discos e quiser movê-los de A para B (sendo C a torre auxiliar). A ideia é:

- mover 4 discos da origem (A) para o auxiliar (C)
- mover o disco 5 para o destino (B)
- mover os 4 discos que estão no auxiliar (C) para o destino (B)

Mas como fazer o primeiro passo (mover 4 discos de A para C)? Simples, eu chamo a função novamente para 4 discos (N - 1), só que considerando que C é o destino e B é o auxiliar. Então ela fará todos os três passos acima, mas considerando esse novo contexto (4 discos, destino é C e B é auxiliar). A mesma coisa para o terceiro passo (só que agora são 4 discos cuja origem é C, destino é B e o auxiliar é A).

---

Por exemplo, se eu tiver 3 discos, a execução fica assim:

- primeiro eu resolvo o problema para 2 discos, movendo de A para C, usando B como auxiliar

  - resolvo para 1 disco, movendo de A para B, usando C como auxiliar
  - movo 2 de A para C
  - resolvo para 1 disco, movendo de B para C, usando A como auxiliar
- movo o disco 3 de A para B
- resolvo para 2 discos, movendo de C para B, usando A como auxiliar

  - resolvo para 1 disco, movendo de C para A, usando B como auxiliar
  - movo 2 de C para B
  - resolvo para 1 disco, movendo de A para B, usando C como auxiliar

Chamando no código, ficaria:

```
hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

Saída:

```
Move disc 1 from tower A to the tower B
Move disc 2 from tower A to the tower C
Move disc 1 from tower B to the tower C
Move disc 3 from tower A to the tower B
Move disc 1 from tower C to the tower A
Move disc 2 from tower C to the tower B
Move disc 1 from tower A to the tower B
```

<sup>[*Veja o código rodando no IdeOne.com*](https://ideone.com/c9iRhJ)</sup>

O que pode confundir é que a cada chamada recursiva, as torres usadas como origem, destino e auxiliar mudam. Mas a lógica é a mesma para as chamadas (mova N - 1 discos da origem para o auxiliar, mova 1 disco da origem para o destino, mova N - 1 discos do auxiliar para o destino).

Lembrando ainda que para N discos, a solução requer 2<sup>N</sup> - 1 passos, e dependendo do N, essa quantidade toda de chamadas recursivas [pode causar um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001). A quantidade exata depende do valor do [*recursion limit*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) (que [pode ser alterado](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)), mas o [valor *default*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40115683) não é tão grande assim ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/46sx8I)).

Comment: Ahhh bem que eu achei estranho o segundo print e nem testei :(

Comment: Mals galera, lógica em aprimoramento hauah Me ajudou muito, obrigado!!!

Comment: @Carlos É normal ter dificuldade com recursão, a primeira vez que vi achei que era bruxaria e demorei muito pra entender. Outra coisa: se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 8):

Esse é um caso que para você entender como foi desenvolvido a função para resolver a torre de Hanoi você precisa considerar que já existe uma função para resolver a torre de Hanoi. Confuso? Não, recursivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos considerar que nosso objetivo é passar os discos de A para C, sendo B nosso auxiliar. Para que o resultado seja válido, o disco 3 deve ser o primeiro em C, correto? Para movermos o disco 3 para C precisaremos mover primeiro os discos 1 e 2 para B.

O problema de mover os discos 1 e 2 para B também é uma torre de Hanoi, mas agora de 2 discos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nesse caso a torre C será nossa auxiliar. Lembra que eu disse no início que você precisa considerar que já existe uma função que resolve a torre de Hanoi? Então, chamamos ela para resolver a torre com 2 discos e teremos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora basta mover o disco 3 para C.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para mover os discos 1 e 2 para C teremos outra torre de Hanoi com 2 discos para resolver, agora com a origem em B, destino em C, com a torre A como auxiliar. Por sorte já temos uma função que resolve isso.

Feito isso, teremos a torre completamente resolvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, para resolver a torre para 3 discos, mudando de A para C, com B auxiliar, fizemos:

1. Resolvemos a torre de Hanoi com 2 discos de A para B, com C auxiliar;
2. Movemos o disco 3 de A para C;
3. Resolvemos a torre de Hanoi com 2 discos de B para C, com A auxiliar;

Correto? Agora reveja o código (simplificado):

```py
def tower_of_hanoi(disc, orig, dest, aux):

    # 1. Resolve a torre de Hanoi para n-1 discos, movendo para o disco auxiliar:
    tower_of_hanoi(disc-1, orig, aux, dest)

    # 2. Move o maior disco para a torre destino:
    print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower {}'.format(disc, orig, dest))

    # 3. Resolve a torre de Hanoi para n-1 discos, movendo da torre auxiliar para a destino:
    tower_of_hanoi(disc - 1, aux, ori, dest)
```

Pronto, a mágica foi feita.

Mas aí você pensa: "Ok, mas como resolver a torre de Hanoi para 2 discos?". Simples, é a mesma lógica (por isso é recursivo). Quando for resolver a torre para 2 discos você antes resolve para 1 disco (n-1), porém, quando você possui apenas 1 disco não tem muito segredo, você pode movê-lo livremente. Com isso criamos a nossa condição de parada da recursividade: se a torre possuir apenas 1 disco, move-o e finaliza a função.

Isso é implementado pelo `if`:

```py
# Se possuir apenas 1 disco:
if disc == 1:
    # Move o disco e finaliza a função
    print('Move disc {} from tower {} to the tower{}'.format(disc, ori, dest))
    return
```

Então, assim, para resolver uma torre de 3 discos ele precisa saber resolver uma de 2 discos; para resolver a de 2 discos precisa saber resolver uma de 1 disco; ele sabe resolver de 1 disco. Isso funcionará para qualquer quantidade de discos e três torres.

Veja [Determinar o n-ésimo termo de Fibonacci com recursividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209187/5878) para mais informações de como funciona a recursividade.

Comment: Para entender recursão, antes vc precisa entender recursão... Eu ia desenhar as torres em ASCII mas fiquei com preguiça, +1 :-)

Comment: Muito boa explicação, pensando desse jeito fica mais fácil de entender a lógica. Vlw msm!!!

Comment: Boa resposta e com direito a ASCII Art.

Answer (score 2):

Uma boa forma de entender como funciona métodos recursivos é entender o padrão dele.
(Facilita bem mais se você pegar a fórmula diretamente, mas enfim)

(Recursividade faz parte de um módulo de exatas: **Análise matemática**)

Primeiro precisamos achar o padrão.

Para mover n disco(s) quantos movimentos são necessários?
disco 1=1 movimento
disco 2=2 movimentos
disco 3=4 movimentos
total de movimentos para 3 discos? 7
total de movimentos para 2 discos? 3
total de movimentos para 1 disco?  1

Então podemos simplificar como notação científica (`f(x)=2**x - 1`) para sabermos quantos movimentos são necessários para completar o puzzle com X discos.

Mas e agora? Como iremos tornar essa função recursiva?

Se `a = {1, 3, 7}` então como faz para ter a2 a partir do a1? Simples! `a2=2*a1+1`

**Então chegamos a formula do método!**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por final, como carambolas funciona este método?

```
def recursivo(n, aux=0):
        if n == 0:
            return aux
        aux+=metodo(n-1, 1)
        aux+=metodo(n-1)
        return aux
```