# Função que retorna outra função retornando ela própria

Tags: javascript

Primeiro de tudo, estou perguntando isso por pura curiosidade, não tem aplicação real onde isso seria útil (ou tem? não sei).

Sei que é possível fazer uma função retornar outra função, e que a função retornada pode ser um parâmetro, ou seja.

```
function a(b) {
    return b();
}
```

Então, se eu passar uma função dentro da função "a", ele retorna o retorno da função que foi usada como parâmetro após sua execução. Exemplificando novamente:

```
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

console.log(a(foo)); // printa 'bar'
```

Até aí, ok.
Entretanto, e quando eu tento invocar a própria função `a` dentro dela mesma?

```
a(a); // erro
```

Eu tentei, e a resposta é um erro informando `b is not a function`.

Queria entender como/por que isso ocorre. Na minha cabeça ele deveria entrar num ciclo de processamento infinito, e travar, ou algo do tipo. Deixei algo passar?

Comment: O que você pretende fazer se chama recursividade. Existem dezenas de perguntas sobre o assunto e uma delas que irá te ajudar é: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202514/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-recursivas-em-javascript

Comment: o nome "a" está gerando confusão, se associar a outra variável deve funcionar: `var x = a;
console.log(a(x));`

Comment: Theotonio, eu entendo o conceito de recursividade, mas neste caso, a recursividade invoca uma função declarada dentro dela mesma. Neste caso, a função iria invocar outra função eterna ao escopo da função original. Não é diferente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deixou passar um detalhe sim. Quando você chama a função `a` é necessário passar um parâmetro, o que não acontece aqui:

```
a(a); // o a de dentro não recebe o parâmetro
```

Então quando `a` executa `return b();` - execução do a interno, sem parâmetro - você recebe o erro porque parâmetro `b` não está definido, já que esse não foi passado.